# How to increase log4j output buffer to log the entire String and not only first 100 chars?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

This is my output for my Log4j logger and as you can see I don't get my entire String written to the log, I only see the first 100 characters in the output log. How can I increase my buffer for my log4j so that I can see the entire String in my log4j?

**service.log output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><child><element name="id" type="String">1</eleme ...
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = ../logs/service.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R
```

**Java Code that Logs**

```
 TextMessage message = createMessage(session);
 logger.info(message.toString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never heard of output being limited by log4j, are you certain this is not what is being returned by message.toString()?

Comment: +1 - I've never experienced problems log4j truncating / limiting messages.

Comment: +1 the config is a straight file appender without buffering. (Why is this tagged as log4j2? This is a log4j-1.x question...)